# Creating video recordings of R Studio and R console

Tags: teaching, statistics, audio-video-recording

I am teaching a course of Methods in the Study of Animal Behaviour and, of course, a large part of the course is dedicated to Statistics and R scripting. COVID-19 emergency and lockdowns are pointing the finger to deliver our teaching using video recordings or online streaming of lessons. I've used various popular apps like Zoom, Skype, and Webex, to give lessons online. I have also been recording my screen using QuickTime and other software. Still, I've never been fully satisfied by the quality of the results when it came to recording the R studio interface. With the perspective of having a semester of full courses online, this worries me a lot. I was wondering whether someone more experienced than me would be happy to share good practices for teaching students using R and R studio via videos, possibly including video editing or the use of different programs for screen recording. Thanks in advance.

Stay Safe!

Comment: If you have a Windows 10 operating system you can record anything with the Game Bar. Simply hold the windows key and press the "g' key to open the game bar. With the Game Bar open go to captures and unmute the microphone. I also recommend increasing the font size of text in Rstudio: Tools > Global Options > Appearance > Editor Font Size.

Answer (score 2):

OBS Studio (https://obsproject.com/) worked well for me for another statistical analysis program. For the very basic editing afterwards (cut the time that the kids ran into the room out of the video, join videos together) the video editor that comes with Windows was enough for me.

Also see: [I need help adapting my academic workflow to the COVID-19/coronavirus crisis – where do I start?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/i-need-help-adapting-my-academic-workflow-to-the-covid-19-coronavirus-crisis-w?cb=1)

Comment: I was going to give the same answer. I've been recently making videos on OBS with Matlab but I think it would work equally fine with RStudio. It works great when you want to show your face, Matlab screen and some pdf, although it might be a bit of overkill if you only want to show RStudio and record your voice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it asap. Regards.